# Back button animation issue in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

I have scenario in that, On click of Tab I am calling **viewWillAppear** method and but after that when I press Back button It will directly back without any animation.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
      switch(mytabbar.selectedIndex)
      {
         case 0:
              [viewController viewWillAppear:YES];
              break;
      }
  }
```

All thing working fine but I don't get Back button animation is only issue

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to call view controller life cycle methods - like `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLoad`. They automatically called throughout the life cycle of a view as and when needed and applicable.

You need to tell us what exactly you want to implement , then we can help you?

Answer (score 0):

On click of back:

```
- (IBAction)onBackButtonClicked:(id)sender{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```